# Importing NetworkX graph to GML keeping the special characters intact

Tags: python, networkx, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I want to write a graph `G` in GML format. My node names (label in GML) contain special characters like `š, č` etc. These are not replicated in the GML file when I do the following.

```
nx.write_gml(G, 'G.gml')
```

Expected output for letters `šč` is `šč`.

Actual output for letter `šč` is `&#353;&#269;`

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in the output are the correct XML character entity codes for the characters you referenced.  It looks like the "nx" facility is producing a GML file with encoding set to something other than UTF-8 which is the most common these days.